# I am unable to create many to one relation in PostgreSQL using spring-boot application.properties?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, many-to-one

GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command :

```
Error executing DDL "
    create table student (
       id  bigserial not null,
        created_time timestamp,
        updated_time timestamp,
        admission_class int4,
        age int8,
        date_of_birth date,
        gender int4,
        name varchar(255),
        parent_or_guardian_remark varchar(255),
        previous_class int4,
        previous_school varchar(255),
        relationship varchar(255),
        parent_details_id id not null,
        teacher_id id not null,
        primary key (id)
    )"
```

via JDBC Statement

Comment: please, provide a code snippets of your entities

Comment: Thank you, here you can find https://github.com/JCharanRaj/school-canvasing